# Tkinter unable to configure

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this problem when I try to run an app that imports turtle:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/panos/Documents/python/challenge_60.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import tkinter as TK
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I have done the below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

```
pip3 install tkinter
```

```
pip3 install PythonTurtle
```

```
pip3 install Tcl
```

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk python3-tk tk-dev
```

```
sudo apt-get install python3-PythonTurtle
```

And, although it is installed, the error still exists. I haven't understand what does wiki says. Could you explain, with all the details, what do I have to do, because I am a newbie at Linux and commands in general?

Comment: What version of Python are you using to run your code?

Answer (score 2):

- This error is probably made, because you have installed the `tkinter` , for instance, on `python 3.7`, but you are running your code with an interpreter based on `python 3.8`.
- Another reasons, like installing the `library` in a `virtual environment` and trying to run the code out of the `venv`, can also
  lead to this error.

---

**Make sure `pip` and `python command` are in the same location/path**
to make sure they are from the same `SDK`.

- This command indicates where python is installed on your machine:
  (`Unix` Only)

```
which python
```

`Windows` users, use this snippet below to find path of the installed python :

```py
import sys
locate_python = sys.exec_prefix
print(locate_python)
```

- Check the `pip` location using the `which` command as well.

```
which pip
```

If `pip` and `python` are in the same path, you probably won't get the error anymore.

Comment: `tkinter` is almost always included in all versions and environments, it would have to be explicitly not installed when installing python

Comment: A note here: to _fix_ this version-installation issue, you can use `python3 -m pip install ...`. This installs in the newest Python 3 version.

Comment: @Matiiss: Maybe the OP's Python version was installed as part of the system installation? The version of Python 3 that was installed by default on my Ubuntu did not come with tkinter; I had to manually install it. So in some cases (however slim, there still is a chance), python does not come with tkinter. Maybe the system excludes tkinter when installing Python.

Comment: @Behdad Abdollahi Moghadam: and how should I update it to python version I use? And I don't know what venv is. I use a book to learn python and this is nowhere. Also, I have the newest python installed (python 3.10). I update it just in case it was needed. I also run Linux Mint Ullysa. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: @ExhaustedCProgrammer I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

First you have to pay attention to a few things 1- All the packs must be updated and installed If you have downloaded the packs, update them, especially the pip module that is for installation 2- Note that the spelling of the words you use is correct 3 - Maybe the code you write does not support that module, you should also pay attention to this issue 4- Finally, there are some problems in your code. First, to download the Tkinter module, you have to write pip3 install tk or pip install tk. You should not write the word Tkinter yourself. Update the latest version and then try again. If it still does not work, turn on your Windows 10 (if not) and finally the last solution is to change your ide vs code. The best ide for this situation. Is And you can also help to install and import the library of online articles. If you use pycharm, enter the Windows command line and type pip3 install future or pip install future, and then the thinner will be imported for you, and then enter the following command: from future.moves import tkinter and you can find how to install each house in different ideas with a simple search

Comment: there is a very slim chance that `tkinter` is not installed already